# Exporting shapefile layer to KML and CRS specification in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, epsg

I've been trying to learn the ins and outs of QGIS for several years now. I am somewhat familiar with the software but certainly not an expert.

I have recently downloaded a section of the Canadian Dominion Land Survey from the province of Manitoba. For example, this file:
http://mli2.gov.mb.ca/quarter_sec/shp_zip_files/reynolds_shp.zip

I can import a layer (for example: sec_line_line.shp) and it asks me to specify the CRS. the one that is selected by default is WGS 84 - EPSG:4326. If I use this CRS I can export the new layer as a KML file. But when I import the KML file into google earth I see lines all over the globe.

I then try adding the OpenLayers Google Maps satellite raster and it complains that "Error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits". I assume this is because google maps rasters want to be in EPSG:3857. So I change the CRS of the project to EPSG:3857, select on-the-fly CRS transformation and add the OpenLayers map source. The map source loads fine, but now I can't see the original DLS data I loaded before (sec_line_line.shp)

I don't understand why this is, or what I can do to fix the issue.

I'm using QGIS 2.18 on Ubuntu 16.4 (Ubuntu 14.4 also does the same thing)

Comment: The [web site](http://mli2.gov.mb.ca/quarter_sec/) says these layers are in NAD83 UTM. It's probably 14 North AKA EPSG::26914.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I filtered the CRS on 26914 and came up with nothing. I then used your suggestion that it was 14 north, this led me to find "EPSG:32614, WGS 84 / UTM zone 14" this one seemed to work. But *how* did you know this? Might be a dumb question, but I don't understand how I could have picked this out?

Comment: On the page I linked to, "Coordinates are in the NAD83 UTM projection." Always check around on the website or data metadata if data itself doesn't have a coordinate reference system. I then looked up Manitoba's lat/lon extent and figured out the zone. It's weird that you couldn't find 26914. It's still valid in EPSG and has been around for a long time.

Comment: Ya, I had definitely found the quote you mentioned, but to me that wasn't enough to determine the precise CRS. I hadn't even considered the the UTM zone would have anything going to do with the CRS. I suppose I have much to learn. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

As mkennedy suggested above, in the CRS selection window, I filtered on 26914 and came up with nothing. I then used their suggestion that it was 14 north, this led me to find "EPSG:32614, WGS 84 / UTM zone 14" this one seemed to work.